The external monitor does not wake up from sleep at 4K resolution
I have Ubuntu Studio 24.04 and Ubuntu 24.04 - the problem is identical on both. Namely, I have a 4K external monitor connected to my laptop. I would like to use the native 4K resolution on both the laptop and the external monitor. Unfortunately, if I use the 4K resolution, every time the computer goes into sleep mode or just screen saver mode, the external screen doesn't wake up. Changing the resolution to a lower one and then back to 4K helps, and everything works until the next sleep. The problem does not occur at resolutions lower than 4K - the external monitor wakes up every time.
I am using an NVIDIA GeForce 2080 RTX graphics card with the nvidia-driver-550 drivers, but I have checked with several earlier versions. The same issue occurs with the Nouveau drivers.
